# Eclipse Maven Not Downloading Sources and Javadoc from Configured Nexus Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I have configured in my global m2 settings the Nexus Repository that my organization is using.

When doing `mvn install` it downloads the packages from the Nexus Repo, which shows the configuration is alright.

When using maven in eclipse however, it appears that whenever I do a Maven > Update Project, and eclipse tries to download the new packages added in pom.xml, it is still downloading from Maven Repo.

[image: Downloading Sources from Central Maven Repo]

I have already configured the following:

- Under Preferences > Maven > Installations, this is pointing to my maven files
- Under Preferences > Maven > User Settings, this is pointing to my settings.xml under my user folder and configured to the nexus repository

However, I am not sure why are packages still not retrieved from nexus repo still.

**My settings.xml**

```
<settings>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>MyId</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>MyRepo</id>
                <url>MyCompanysNexusRepoUrl</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>MyRepo</id>
                <url>MyCompanysNexusRepoUrl</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>MyId</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Please show your `settings.xml`....cause I assume it is not done correctly...

Comment: Shared with thanks! @khmarbaise

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `settings.xml` for using a repository manager like Nexus should look like this:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url> MyCompanysNexusRepoUrl</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a network with restriction, you might have to add proxy details in eclipse.